# XSLT transform dynamic values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Need help in transforming below xml..tried various things ..not able to .

```
<State>
<School>
<Name>ABC</Name>
<Strength>100</Strength>
</School>

<School>
<Name>XYZ</Name>
<Strength>100</Strength>
</School>
</State>
```

TO

Name is removed and school dynamically to be changed to Name

```
<State>
<ABC>
<Strength>100</Strength>
</ABC>

<XYZ>
<Strength>100</Strength>
</XYZ>
</State>
```

Comment: **1.** The input you show is not well-formed XML. **2.** Post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of writing your code for you from scratch. **3.** If you're using libxslt, then you're **not** using XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Discover confirm if below solution is working?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" /> <xsl:output method="xml" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<State>
<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
</State> 
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/State/School">
<xsl:element name="{Name}"> 
<xsl:copy-of select="Strength"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```